# NPE in nearby.sharing

Tags: android

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at cpqb.w (:com.google.android.gms@230914041@23.09.14 (150800-515650844))
  at com.google.android.gms.nearby.sharing.DeviceVisibilityChimeraActivity.o
  at com.google.android.gms.nearby.sharing.DeviceVisibilityChimeraActivity.onStart ()
  at gxi.public_onStart (:com.google.android.gms@230914041@23.09.14 (150800-515650844))
  at gxj.onStart (:com.google.android.gms@230914041@23.09.14 (150800-515650844):1)
  at xrg.onStart (:com.google.android.gms@230914041@23.09.14 (150800-515650844))
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1467)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:8099)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:3732)
```

I get this issue with pre launch testing on [Generic Small Desktop (x86) (virtual), 1366x768, Android 12L (SDK 32)]. It obviously looks like an issue with Nearby devices share feature and nothing to do with our code. Has anyone seen this issue before?